# Remove object from ArrayList<> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanna remove object from  my ArrayList. But its not working as expected. Below is my code.

```
public static void validateXML(ArrayList<MyClass> ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs,boolean result)
    {
        MyClass MyclassObject = new MyClass();
        if(result == true)
        {
            // code
        }
        else
        {
            ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs.remove(MyclassObject.requestFile);
        }
    }
```

but the value is not  getting removed. What's wrong with is code?

Comment: Pretty much everything...it doesn't really make any sense at all, sorry. Maybe try and explain what you are trying to do and show some of the context around the code you posted.

Comment: You should first post enough code for anyone to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: `ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs` is arrayList of class `MyClass`, and you pass attribute of `MyClass` object in .remove method

Comment: post your whole code ..

Comment: Your code is suspicious from several reasons... please try to read more about java basics and OOP at all. Your code looks to me like school lesson "find as much errors as you can". It is problematic from the very biggining. public-WHY? static-WHY? void-no removal result? validateXML-what?!? ArrayList-use generics? ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs-use java standard variable name conventions, result-name of input parameter result? The code itself is so strange that I dont dare to comment it.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable  `ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs` is of the type

```
ArrayList<MyClass>
```

which means it contains only instances of `MyClass`. On the other hand, you try to remove

```
MyclassObject.requestFile
```

from it, which doesn't at all look like an instance of the  `MyClass` type.

NB `MyclassObject` is an instance you have just created. Therefore that very instance is definitely *not* in the list and there would be no point in correcting your code to remove `MyclassObject` from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove an object that has not the same type of the List. Probably, changing to the code below will solve the problem:

```
ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs.remove(MyclassObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I try to guess what you going to do. May be you want to remove object that have same requestFile as it in your MyclassObject. Then you must do something like that:

```
public static void validateXML(ArrayList<MyClass> ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs,boolean result)
{
    MyClass MyclassObject = new MyClass();
    if(result == true)
    {
        // code
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<MyClass> itemsToDelete = new ArrayList<MyClass>(ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs.size());
        for (MyClass item : ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs) {
            if (item.requestFile.equals(MyclassObject.requestFile)) {
                itemsToDelete.add(item);
            }
        }
        ArrayvalidRequestResponsePairs.removeAll(itemsToDelete);
    }
}
```

But this still not have sense, because you create new MyClass right before filtering and probably field requestFile of this object is null. Anyway, this is quite strange behavior of method. Can you explain what do you want to do?